# What is the effect of bundle READ policies in DSpace?

Tags: dspace

The authorizations GUI interface presents `item`, `bundle` and `bitstream` policies. What is the effect of `bundle` `READ` policies in DSpace?

I tested the functionality and could not observe any effect in changing or removing the bundle `READ` policy:

- Having a more restrictive bundle policy than bitstream policy does not lock down the bitstream further,
- having a more permissive bundle policy than bitstream policy does not give more open access to the bitstream,
- the bundle policy does not effect the bitstream access in absence of a bitstream policy,
- all bitstreams are still listed in absence of a bundle policy.

So what is the bundle `READ` policy's purpose and why does it appear in the authorizations GUI interface?

Answer (score 0):

I got the hint on DSpace's Slack and could verify in DSpace source, that *in some cases*, a newly added `bitstream` is given a policy with the same access rights than its `bundle`'s `READ` policy upon upload.

In other cases, e.g. when installing a new `item`, the `DEFAULT_BITSTREAM_READ` policy of an item's `collection` serves this purpose.